# Are there any sparklyr arguments to return extra log info during kafka topic consuming streams with R?

Tags: r, apache-kafka, stream, sparklyr

After managing to establish a connection with kafka, when trying to consume a topic nothing returns back, an I'm curious if any relevant arguments can be passed to get extra logs on what is going on.
A progress bar emerges above my console, and makes me feel that everything works fine.[image]

Answer (score 1):

`spark_log(sc, n = NULL)` seems to return useful info